# Django : Dropdown menu to show only unconfigured values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have created two models -

```
class DID_Definition_Model(models.Model):   # DID to Region-Carrier Mapping
    region_carrier = models.ForeignKey(Telco_Carrier_Mapper_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    did_number= models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[alphanumeric], primary_key=True)
    did_cost= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_on_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class DID_Number_Assignment_Model(models.Model):       #DID Number Assignment
    did_selector = models.ForeignKey(DID_Definition_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    subscriber_department=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    usage_assignment=models.ForeignKey(Usage_Assignment_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_email=models.EmailField()
    employee_fullname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And created the below view -

```
def did_assignment_form(request, did_selector=0):
    if request.method =="GET":
        if did_selector==0:
            form = DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form()
        else:
            did_assignment_item = DID_Number_Assignment_Model.objects.get(pk=did_selector)
            form = DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form(instance=did_assignment_item)
        return render(request, 'MASTERHANDLER/did_assignment_form.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        if id==0:
            context = DID_Number_Assignment_Model.objects.values('did_selector')
            if did_selector not in context: 
                form = DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form(request.POST)
        else:
            did_assignment_item = DID_Number_Assignment_Model.objects.get(pk=did_selector)
            form = DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form(request.POST, instance = did_assignment_item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('did_assignment_list')
```

Form detail below -

```
class DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DID_Number_Assignment_Model
        fields = ('did_selector', 'usage_assignment', 'employee_fullname', 'employee_email',  'subscriber_department' )
        labels = {
            'did_selector' : 'DID Selector',
            'usage_assignment' : 'Number Usage ',
            'employee_fullname' : 'Employee Full Name',
            'employee_email' : 'Employee Email',
            'subscriber_department' : 'Employee Department',    

        }



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # TO SET drop down default text for a field , optional -
        self.fields['did_selector'].empty_label = "Select"
        self.fields['usage_assignment'].empty_label = "Select"
        # TO SET a field which may be optional -
        self.fields['subscriber_department'].required = False
        #self.fields['region_assigned'].required = False
```

This form works with no problems but with one little oddity. If I create an object in DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form with 'did_selector' field as the foreign key, the very same value of 'did_selector' is shown for the next creation process.

My question is that how can I show only those did selector values which have not been configured. Sample screenshot below -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer. What essentially I was looking for a method to over ride the queryset on a select field to exclude options already used.

I did this under forms.py by first creating a queryset and getting  required values for a specific field.
Then assign these values as default using 'queryset' keyword on the field.

```
defs_with_no_assignments = DID_Definition_Model.objects.filter(did_number_assignment_model__isnull=True)

available_did= defs_with_no_assignments.values_list('did_number', flat=True)
self.fields['did_selector'].queryset = available_did
```